# Principal symbol of the Lie Derivative (w.r.t a fixed vector field) as a differential operator?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles

Is it reasonable to think of the Lie derivative with respect to a fixed vector field ($\mathcal L_X$) as a differential operator? If so, what is its principal symbol?

Comment: I think there are a lot of conventions about how you define or understand symbols, but the Lie derivative, acting on some bundle of tensor fields, is a differential operator of order $1$. Its symbol is $\sigma(\mathcal L_X) ( T) = T\otimes X$.

Comment: The definition that I am referring to is the one in Section 2.1 of 'Ricci Flow: An introduction' by Chow and Knopf. They define the symbol of the differential operator $\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}L_\alpha\partial^\alpha$ in the direction of a covector field $\zeta$ as $\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}L_\alpha\zeta^\alpha$, where $\zeta^\alpha:=\zeta^{\alpha_1}\zeta^{\alpha_2}...\zeta^{\alpha_n}$.

Comment: Ok, take a look at [the coordinate expression for the Lie-derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#Coordinate_expressions). From this you can read off that in your notation the principal symbol is $\sum_c X^c\Bbb 1 \xi^c$. ($\Bbb1$ is the identity morphism of the fibres of the bundle you are looking at) (In the previous comment I also meant principal symbol, not symbol.)